# Change style programmatically for api less than 23

Tags: java, android

I want to change the button's style using setTextAppearance but, throw "depreciated".how to use setTextAppearance  correctly?

styles.xml

```html
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="button_custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#FFF59D</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FFF59D</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And the activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btn;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    context = this;

    btn.setTextAppearance(context,R.style.button_custom);

}

public void setTextAppearance(Context context, int resId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        super.setTextAppearance(context, resId);
    }
    else { super.setTextAppearance(resId);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making your button of AppCompatButton type and use

```
btn.setTextAppearance(resid)
```

It will also helps you avoid the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT branching

You can follow this documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html#setTextAppearance(android.content.Context, int)

User AppCompatButton

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
       android:id="@+id/some_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: btn.setTextAppearance(resid) does not work for API less than 23. I check the documentation but  i cant find the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer section. You can use that and see if it helps

Comment: I try with AppCompatButtonand say "depreciated" on setTextAppearance(context, resId);

Comment: Now i use API 24 and don't do anything.. maybe i skipped one step. The button looks with the old style.